# active_support dependencies error when using candy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activesupport, candy

I am getting the following error when I use Candy in my Rails project. Really a syntax error?

```
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /home/waleed/.bundler/ruby/1.8/candy-daa2670a71e3/lib/candy/array.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
...lection.find_and_modify query: {"_id" => @__candy_parent.id}...
                              ^
/home/waleed/.bundler/ruby/1.8/candy-daa2670a71e3/lib/candy/array.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
...{"_id" => @__candy_parent.id}, update: {'$pop' => {@__candy_...
                              ^
/home/waleed/.bundler/ruby/1.8/candy-daa2670a71e3/lib/candy/array.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
... {@__candy_parent_key => -1}}, new: false
                              ^
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
  from /home/waleed/.bundler/ruby/1.8/candy-daa2670a71e3/lib/candy/piece.rb:1
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/SFEley/candy), the Candy gem only works on Ruby 1.9 -- you're using 1.8.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be the issue. I've installed 1.9 version but apparently my rails project is still using 1.8. How can I direct rails to use the latest version?